# How to set column on right side of editor plug-in eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, text-editor, multiple-columns

I created column in custom editor in eclipse plug in project, but it is on left side of editor, how i can force it to be on right side of editor?
My column extends org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberRulerColumn.

My editor should looks like this:

left column | editor | right column

Left and right columns will contain codes, addresses and asm code. How i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can easily. The ruler on the right hand side of the text editor is the `overview ruler` used for showing annotations.

The right hand ruler is created by `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createOverviewRuler`, you could try overriding that.